# Expecation for tensor products

Tags: quantum-mechanics

We are told that $$Z|0 \rangle = | 0\rangle  \\ Z | 1\rangle =-|1\rangle \\ X|0\rangle =|1\rangle \\ X|1\rangle =|0\rangle$$

and we have the state $$|\psi\rangle =|0\rangle |1\rangle +|1\rangle |0\rangle$$

The question is: Without doing an explicit calculation explain why expectation of Z*X and X*Z in the given state are the same?

My answer: I kind of done the calculation in my head and said that "For the right hand side of both inner products Z will only change the coefficient of a ket while X will switch the ket, resulting in tensor products of similar kets i.e either $|0\rangle|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle |1\rangle$. This won't match up to the left hand side $\langle\psi|$ which means both expectations will be zero."

I don't think this is the non-calculation answer they were looking for. X and Z do not commute, my only other guess is because the state is entangled. Are there any properties linear operators can have that make their expectations the same either way round?

Answer (score 1):

I assume $Z*X$ means the operator that acts as $Z$ on the first tensor factor and as $X$ on the second, and analogously for $X*Z$.  If so, then $Z*X=T\cdot(X*Z)\cdot T$, where $T$ is the linear operator that interchanges the two tensor factors.  Using this and the fact that your particular state $|\psi\rangle$ satisfies $T|\psi\rangle=|\psi\rangle$ and $\langle\psi|T=\langle\psi|$, you get
$$
\langle\psi|Z*X|\psi\rangle=\langle\psi|T(X*Z)T|\psi\rangle=\langle\psi|X*Z|\psi\rangle.
$$
I'm not sure whether this counts as an explicit computation and is therefore prohibited.  If so, I recommend meditating on the equations (or on symmetry) instead of writing them.